# Как перевести полученные данные из строки в JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

есть html список содержащий в атребуте data данные в таком формате

```
{'price':'1050','kpp':'МКПП'},{'price':'1100','kpp':'АКПП'}
```

Пример html эелмента

```
<div data-type="{'price':'1050','kpp':'МКПП'},{'price':'1100','kpp':'АКПП'}">Golf</div>
```

попробовал вот так

```js
typekpp = $('div').data('type');
type = JSON.parse(typekpp);
console.log(type);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-type="{'price':'1050','kpp':'МКПП'},{'price':'1100','kpp':'АКПП'}">Golf</div>
```

но выдает ошибку, с JSON раньше не работал, подскажите как решить данную задачу?

у меня есть возможность переформатировать атрибут data, можете быть его как то видоизменить??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас здесь три ошибки:

1. В JSON должны быть двойные кавычки **""**, а не одинарные **''**.
2. Не верная структура **JSON**, это наверное должен быть массив объектов.
3. **jQuery** делает медвежью услугу. Он видит, что в `data-type` валидный **JSON** и сам преобразует его к объекту.

Посмотрите рабочий пример.

```js
var typekpp = $('div').data('type');
console.log(typekpp, typekpp[0].price);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-type='[{"price":"1050","kpp":"МКПП"},{"price":"1100","kpp":"АКПП"}]'>Golf</div>
```